# Why does Arial Black default to italic in CorelDRAW?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, coreldraw

I am dual-booting Windows XP and Windows 7, using CorelDRAW on both.
Using XP, I have no problems, however in Windows 7 the font Arial Black defaults to italic. After removing the italic attribute, I try to convert the CorelDRAW file to JPEG, however, once more, the italic version of Arial Black appears.

This problem applies only to Arial Black; all other fonts work fine. As you can see in the GIF below, when I move the text area (when the font is non-italic), the movement preview shows an italic shadow, and the text turns italic when released.

I have attempted re-downloading the font as well as copy+pasting text written in Arial Black – the symptoms still persist. 
What/why is happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You should edit your wall of text - Will make it a lot easier for everyone to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: @Bungicasse i did not get what u mean. U mean that the question which i have posted should be in short?

Comment: Yes you should edit your question, I think people have a hard time figuring out what your actual problem is.

Comment: atek, your question makes no sense. Use proper English please. Otherwise, people will have a hard time understanding what you say. That means very little chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a win 7 and XP virtual machine with the same font problem. Also it disables the whole Arial font sometimes. Somewhere in the system there's a bug. The only solution I have is to use Fontnavigator and manually enable Arial black, then close and open the file in Corel.

Comment: where can i get font navigator

Comment: It is part of the Corel suite

Comment: IM USING COREL 12 OLD VERSION DOES COREL 12 ALSO HAVE FONT NAVIGATOR?

Comment: If you have the suite, certainly. But you have to look yourself on the stuff you have. Perhaps it is also included with a single Draw package.

Comment: single draw package? can u plz send me a link thanks

Comment: No, I think you misunderstand me. This is not free downloadable software. If you bought a standalone version of CorelDraw! then it should be included. If you want to use a free fontmanager, try http://codeandrun.com/john/font-runner-2/font-runner/

Comment: Did you succeed?